# Change values in data.frame conditionally

Tags: r

I am trying to check the value of one variable and if it meets a certain condition the new variable  gets set to 1 or else it gets  set to zero.

I am having difficulty with this in R.

This simple code does not work:

```
attach(data)
if (Drug = 1) {
   Drug_factor <- 0
} else {
   if (Drug = 2) {
      Drug_factor <- 1
   } else  Drug_factor<- 0
```

I do not understand why this will not work.
Why does R use such complicated conventions for doing basic stuff ?

Comment: Please don't `attach` the 'data'.  You can use `ifelse` i.e. `v1 <- with(Data, ifelse(Drug==1, 0, ifelse(Drug==2, 1, 0)))`  or even without two `ifelse` this can be done.  But an example would be useful as I don't know how your data looks like.

Comment: If there are only two values in 'Drug', we can use `with(Data, factor(Drug, levels=1:2, labels=0:1))` or can be done by other means as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `ifelse`

```
Data$Drug_factor <- with(Data, ifelse(Drug==1, 0, 1))
```

Or use the `factor` approach

```
Data$Drug_factor <- with(Data, as.numeric(as.character(factor(Drug, 
                levels=1:2, labels=0:1))))
```

Or

```
Data$Drug_factor <- c(0,1)[(Data$Drug==2)+1]
```

Or even shorter assuming that the 'Drug' is 'numeric'

```
Data$Drug_factor <- c(0,1)[Data$Drug]
```

All these cases, assume that there are only two `unique` elements in 'Drug'.

---

Suppose if you have more than 2 unique elements in 'Drug', from the code, it seems to me that only when 'Drug==2', the value should be returned as 1.  Creating another value in 'Drug'

```
Data$Drug[4] <- 3
```

In this case, we can change the `ifelse` condition such that when 'Drug' is 2 return 1 and for all others to return 0.

```
Data$Drug_factor <-  with(Data, ifelse(Drug==2, 1, 0))
```

A similar option by indexing is,

```
Data$Drug_factor <- c(0,1)[(Data$Drug==2)+1]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
Data <- data.frame(Drug= sample(1:2, 10, replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two different kinds of problems of this kind.

In the simple case, you want to change a small number of values to some other value. For this purpose, I find that using `mapvalues()` from plyr is a good solution. For example:

```
#lets pretend we have loaded some data where missing data is coded as 99
set.seed(1) #reproducible results
test_data = sample(c(0:5, 99), size = 1000, replace = T)
#table of our dta
table(test_data)
```

Output:

```
test_data
  0   1   2   3   4   5  99 
138 145 150 150 127 142 148
```

Recode:

```
#recode 99 to NA
library(plyr)
test_data_noNA = mapvalues(test_data, 99, NA)
table(test_data_noNA, exclude = NULL) #also count NAs
```

Output:

```
test_data_noNA
   0    1    2    3    4    5 <NA> 
 138  145  150  150  127  142  148
```

---

In the other case, you want to conditionally change values to some other value, but there is a large/indefinite/infinite number of values it could be.

Example:

```
#continuous data
set.seed(1) #reproducible results
test_data = rnorm(1000) #normally distributed data
hist(test_data) #plot with histogram
```

[image]

However, let's say we want to deal with outliers, which we define at beyond 2SD from the mean. However, we don't just want to exclude them, so instead we will recode them.

```
#change values above 2 to 2
test_data[test_data > 2] = 2
#change valuesbelow -2 to -2
test_data[test_data < -2] = -2
hist(test_data) #plot with histogram
```

[image]